# How to determine if user input is in a rich text editor (on all sites)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, translation

I'm working on a Chrome translation extension that allows users to select a text and press a key (T) to display the translation directly behind the text.

But if the user selects text and presses (T) in the input box, the extension will also show the translation result, which is not what I want.  Fortunately, the input field is usually wrapped around the `<input></input>` tag, so I can tell that the user does not trigger the translation function when the `<input>` tag is used.

```js
if (keyCode == "T") {
    let userSelection = window.getSelection();
    let userSelectionNode = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement;
    if ($(userSelectionNode).find("input").length == 0) {
        let userSelection_string = userSelection.toString();
        if (userSelection_string.length > 0) {
            getTranslate(userSelection_string);
        }
    }
}
```

But if the user is in a rich text editor, my method doesn't work, and I can't tell if the user is in a rich text editor.  So do I have a way to tell if the user is in a rich text editor?
 It is important to note that the extension runs on all web pages, so the method should be generic and not targeted at a particular rich text editor

Comment: What type of element is the rich text editor? Please share more information, code, etc...

Comment: A rich text editor is a place on a web page where you can edit text.  For example, I'm using this input field when I reply to you.  The question might be changed to, what do all rich text editors have in common?  WOxxOm's answer is what I wanted.

Comment: Yep, I know what a rich text editor is, there are several implementations of the concept and html element should be a textarea. Some of them are wrapped in an iframe, like tinyMCE so then your solution might have been different, that's why I asked what type of element it was. But glad that wOxxOm could help you and you solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

They use `contenteditable` attribute, which you can detect easily:

```js
let el = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement;

if (!el.closest('[contenteditable="true"], [contenteditable=""], input, textarea')) {
  // not in a text input
  // .........
}
```